# How to apply patch from git.kernel?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, patch

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on **Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05**. The touchpad doesn't work and I read on multiple forums it's a common problem.

I tried to update kernel using Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer GUI app to `5.10.2` but I probably need (according to https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5867550.html) to apply this patch:

```
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/pinctrl/pinctrl-amd.c?h=v5.10&id=47a0001436352c9853d72bf2071e85b316d688a2
```

I can't figure out how to do that. I've downloaded the compressed `tar.gz` file but now I'm stuck since I don't know how to do the patch.

I've tried `sudo patch linux-47a0001436352c9853d72bf2071e85b316d688a2.tar.gz` but that seems to do nothing (just hangs).

Do you know how to fix it? It should be fixed in the next kernel version but I can't wait.

EDIT: The touchpad works in BIOS.

EDIT: After following @dariofac's answer, it looked good but it raises error:

```
BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole version v1.15 is too old, need at least v1.16
Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1164: vmlinux] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you install it from a `.deb` or did you compile it from source?

Comment: @dariofac To update the kernel I used GUI (Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer). To apply the patch, I just don't know how, I've downloaded the tar.gz but can't figure it out.

Comment: It seems that Mainline downloads a pre-built kernel (the one you can find here https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.2/amd64/) and installs it as a normal `.deb` file.

Comment: @dariofac Thanks, it seems to work, the kernel is updated and touchpad recognized, although it still does not work. I need to check of other solutions probably.

Comment: the files you can find in the link I posted are not patched. To install the patched kernel, you have to follow the guide I posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple guide to compile and install a kernel starting from sources. I did not test this guide with the `.tag.gz` linked, so my recommendation is to take a backup of the whole system before trying to install it.

## Requirements

To compile a kernel, you need to install some requirements first. To do so, issue:

```
sudo apt install git fakeroot build-essential ncurses-dev xz-utils libssl-dev bc flex libelf-dev bison
```

## Extract sources

From the directory where you downloaded the archive, issue:

```
tar -xvzf linux-47a0001436352c9853d72bf2071e85b316d688a2.tar.gz
```

Move to the newly created directory using `cd linux-47a0001436352c9853d72bf2071e85b316d688a2`.

## Configure kernel

Before compiling the kernel, you need to select which modules to include.

To copy the modules of your current kernel, just issue:

```
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
```

If now you issue `make menuconfig` a configuration window opens up and from there you can enable or disable every available module.

## Compile and install kernel

To start compiling the kernel, issue:

```
make
```

and answer to the questions which may arise (they depend on the starting kernel and the kernel being compiled). This step will take a lot of time.

After this step, you have to install modules by issuing:

```
make modules_install
```

Also this step will take some time to complete.

Finally, to install the kernel issue:

```
sudo make install
```

## Enable kernel on boot

To enable kernel on boot, issue:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k <version>
```

where you need to replace `<version>` with the version you actually compiled.

After this, update grub by issuing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Looked good but eventually it printed this error: `BTF: .tmp_vmlinux.btf: pahole version v1.15 is too old, need at least v1.16
Failed to generate BTF for vmlinux
Try to disable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF
make: *** [Makefile:1164: vmlinux] Error 1
`

Comment: @Milano try downloading this http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dwarves-dfsg/dwarves_1.17-1_amd64.deb and installing it (using `dpkg -i dwarves_1.17-1_amd64.deb`)

Comment: I've upgraded to 20.10 and run the commands again. Now I'm waiting for the finish. Thanks